# itext5 pdfreader.debugmode not found in itext7

Tags: java, itext

You are right. Let me try to be clearer :
A client provide me a lot of invoice to process and for each invoice two or more another documents (of type word,PNG or PDF) are associated.
My process has to merge each invoice with its related documents into one PDF document.
I use PdfReader and PdfMerge Itext7 utility tool to do this process. But for one invoice, when I try to merge a PDF document this error  occurs:
com.itextpdf.io.IOException: Error at file pointer 19,453.          at com.itextpdf.io.source.PdfTokenizer.throwError(PdfTokenizer.java:686)    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readDictionary(PdfReader.java:788) at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readObject(PdfReader.java:710)     at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readObject(PdfReader.java:666)     at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readObject(PdfReader.java:1203)        at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readObject(PdfReader.java:1207)        at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readObject(PdfReader.java:662)     at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfIndirectReference.getRefersTo(PdfIndirectReference.java:126)          at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfIndirectReference.getRefersTo(PdfIndirectReference.java:130)          at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.get(PdfDictionary.java:463)        at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.get(PdfDictionary.java:151)        at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:1868)          at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.(PdfDocument.java:251)     at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.PdfDocument.java:233)          .....
Caused by: com.itextpdf.io.IOException: Dictionary key -e is not a name.

In itext5 version, I just set PdfMerge.debugmode.
I wanted to know how I could find a workaround with itext7 to merge anyway this file as I could do it in itext5.
Thank for your help!!!

Comment: As far as I can see there is no equivalent in iText 7. And even in iText 5 it was by name merely a *debugging* help, not for production use. You call those PDFs *not ISO320001 conform* but more adequate would be *broken*. If you know the exact way they are broken, you should consider repairing them before processing them.

Comment: Thank you MLK. The main cause of these broken pdf is related to dictionnary key. Is there a way when like errors happen at runtime to rebuild the dictionnary key and repair these files using itext facilities?

Comment: Your description of the exact problem with the PDFs still only gives a hazy idea. Concerning repair options, therefore, I can only say "Maybe."